# Matplotlib figure size increased with added label?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a figure with `fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))` and I find that adding a label for one axes will increase the figure size from a square 5*5 to a rectangular one. I wonder is this normal and why label takes extra space beyond the pre-defined figure size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure size never changes from the specified size. If you find that it does, you should [report a bug](https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/index.html). Of course, labels have to go somewhere so the *margins* are increased:

```py
xdata = range(5)
ydata = [x**2 for x in xdata]

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.show()

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.ylabel("ylabel") # label for single axis
plt.show()
```

[image: plot comparison]

If this is what you see, then it is indeed normal because if the margins didn't increase the labels wouldn't fit in the image.

---

You have some control over how far away the label is from the axes bounding box (including ticks and tick labels) by specifying a `labelpad` distance in pt:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.ylabel("ylabel", labelpad = -100)
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.ylabel("ylabel", labelpad = 100)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot comparison labelpad]