# Matplotlib figure size dose not match the pixel length?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used following code to create a figure with size 3 in by 3 in and dpi 157 (ppi of my laptop screen). Thus I expect the size of the figure to be 3 in on my screen, but it is smaller than 3 in as I measured it by ruler (somewhere around 2.8 inch). What gives this inconsistence? Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with plt.style.context('dark_background'):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=157)
    plt.subplot()
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,3,2])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: are you wanting the whole figure to be 3in x 3in or just the axes?

Comment: @tdy I'm not sure. I did this to learn how figure size are determined in matplotlib. In the case only one axis exist on a figure, does the figure size differ with the axis size? I don't understand.

Comment: yes, the figure size includes stuff like labels, margins, etc.

Comment: @tdy I'm confused because when adding labels the size of the figure increases . I asked this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132091/matplotlib-figure-size-increased-with-added-label

Comment: Ah ok, with the new picture I can see that you weren't only measuring the axes. Then I'm not sure.

Comment: 1) Your screen may have a pixel ratio set.  2) if you ask this question it would help to say what backend you are using.  3) if you use figbox_inches='tight' that will also change the size of a saved figure.

Comment: When I run OP's code in jupyter with backend `module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline`, I'm also getting 2.8in width. When I run it on the command line with backend `TkAgg`, I get 3in width.

Comment: @JodyKlymak is this an expected discrepancy between `pylab.backend_inline` and `TkAgg`?

Comment: The online backend uses bbox_inches=tight

Comment: ... and bbox_inches='tight' will trim extra white space from the edge of the figure.